# How do I transfer files and pictures from my galaxy s7 edge to ubuntu 18.04 lts?

Tags: file-sharing, smartphone

Im new to ubuntu and would like to transfer files and media from my smartphone to my ubuntu laptop. What drivers and/or packages do i need to have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install `GSConnect` on Ubuntu, and `KDE Connect` on your Android smart phone.

This extension enables you to connect your phone or other devices to your
system, sending remote sms, see phone calls, share notifications, send files.

To connect an Android device, install the KDE Connect Android app from
the Google Play Store or F-Droid.

GSConnect is a complete KDE Connect protocol implementation for Gnome Shell
with Nautilus, contacts and Shell integration.

- In `terminal` (or Synaptic)...

`sudo apt-get update` # update the software databases

`sudo apt-get install gnome-shell-extension-gsconnect` # install gsconnect

`sudo apt-get install gnome-shell-extension-gsconnect-browsers` # browser support

- Install `KDE Connect` from the `Google Play Store`...

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.kde.kdeconnect_tp

Answer (score 1):

Here are 2 relatively simple ways-

1. Use a USB cord. You should be able to set Nautilus to mount your phone's drives when you plug it in.  I'm on Lubuntu with PCManFM instead of Nautilus, so I can't give you the step-by-step - maybe somebody else can help with that.
2. Install Filezilla (an FTP client) on your computer from the repository (Menu > System Tools > Synaptic Package Manager). Then install an FTP server app on your phone- I use FTP Server Pro but there are many choices in Google Play store.
   Start the FTP server on your phone, and note the phone's IP address and other details (port #, login, etc).
   Start Filezilla on your computer, click File, Site Manager, and connect to your phone. A search on how to use Filezilla will bring up lots of resources.  It's not terribly complicated but I won't try to write it all out in detail, and you'll have some choices (port, authentication, etc) which you'll need to make consistent between the server on the phone and the Filezilla client on your computer.

Answer (score 0):

First, connect your smartphone to the Ubuntu system using a USB Data cable. As soon as you connect your smartphone to your laptop, You will get a prompt on your smartphone with options such as charging, Data transfer. Select Data Transfer. Then open file manager(Nautilus) on your laptop. You will see your phone detected as portable storage. Click on it and browse the files.